# PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 62? Can't figure it out

Tags: php

I have an ajax slider in wordpress which is generating  the Invalid Argument error which seems to stem from

```
<li class="portfolio-col-<?php echo $portfolio_column_count++; ?>" data-portfolio="portfolio-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-id="id-<?php echo $idCount++; ?>" data-type="<?php foreach ($portfolio_cats as $taxonomy) { echo 'filter-' . $taxonomy->slug . ' '; } ?>">
```

which is line 62 form the code below. I can't figure it out so nay help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="ajax-portfolio-block-wrap">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php $page_title=get_the_title(); ?>

                <div class="ajax-gallery-navigation">
                    <div id="ajax-portfolio-loading"></div>
                    <a class="ajax-navigation-arrow ajax-prev" href="#">Prev</a>
                    <a class="ajax-navigation-arrow ajax-next" href="#">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ajax-portfolio-window">
                    <div id="ajax-portfolio-wrap"></div>
                </div>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    $idCount=1;
    $columns=4;
    ?>
    <div class="fullpage-contents-wrap">
        <div class="page-container">
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <h2 class="ajax-projects-title"><?php echo $page_title; ?></h2>
                <div class="portfolio-works-wrap">
                        <ul class="portfolio-filter clearfix">
                        <li class="current all"><a href="#"><?php _e('All','mthemelocal'); ?></a></li>
                        <?php                   
                        $categories=  get_categories('child_of='.$portfolio_cat_ID.'&orderby=slug&taxonomy=types&title_li=');
                        foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>
                        <li class="<?php echo "filter-" . $category->slug;?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $category->name;?></a></li>
                        <?php }?>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-filter-wrap clearfix">
                    <ul class="portfolio-list">
                        <?php
                        $newquery = array(
                            'post_type' => 'mtheme_portfolio',
                            'types' => $portfolio_cat_slug,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            );
                        query_posts($newquery);
                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                        $custom = get_post_custom(get_the_ID());
                        $portfolio_cats = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'types' );
                        $video_url="";
                        $thumbnail="";
                        $link_url="";
                        if ( isset($custom["video"][0]) ) { $video_url=$custom["video"][0]; }
                        if ( isset($custom["thumbnail"][0]) ) { $thumbnail=$custom["thumbnail"][0]; }
                        if ( isset($custom["custom_link"][0]) ) { $link_url=$custom["custom_link"][0]; }
                        $portfolio_thumb_header=$custom["portfolio_page_header"][0];

                        if ($portfolio_column_count>$columns) $portfolio_column_count=1;

                        ?>
                       // ** Line 62 ** // <li class="portfolio-col-<?php echo $portfolio_column_count++; ?>" data-portfolio="portfolio-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-id="id-<?php echo $idCount++; ?>" data-type="<?php foreach ($portfolio_cats as $taxonomy) { echo 'filter-' . $taxonomy->slug . ' '; } ?>">
                            <span class="ajax-image-selector"></span>

                            <?php
                            if ( $custom["video"][0]<>"" ) {
                                $p_class="fadethumbnail-play";
                            } elseif ( $custom["custom_link"][0]<>"" ) {
                                $p_class="fadethumbnail-link";
                            } else {
                                $p_class="fadethumbnail-view";
                            }
                            ?>
                                <?php
                                    if ($portfolio_thumb_header=="Slideshow") {
                                        echo '<a class="portfolio-image-link portfolio-ajax" rel="'.$post->ID.'" ref="'.$video_url.'" >';
                                        echo '<span class="column-portfolio-icon portfolio-slideshow-icon"></span>';
                                        } else {                            
                                            if ( $custom["video"][0]<>"" ) { 
                                                echo '<a class="portfolio-image-link portfolio-ajax" rel="'.$post->ID.'" ref="'.$video_url.'" >';
                                                echo '<span class="column-portfolio-icon portfolio-video-icon"></span>';
                                                } elseif ( $custom["custom_link"][0]<>"" ) {

                                                    echo '<a class="portfolio-image-link portfolio-ajax" rel="'.$post->ID.'" ref="'.$custom["custom_link"][0].'" >';
                                                    echo '<span class="column-portfolio-icon portfolio-image-icon"></span>';

                                                } else {
                                                echo '<a class="portfolio-image-link portfolio-ajax" rel="'.$post->ID.'" ref="'.featured_image_link($post->ID).'" >';
                                                echo '<span class="column-portfolio-icon portfolio-image-icon"></span>';
                                            }
                                    }
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                // Show Image
                                if ($thumbnail<>"") {
                                    echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'" class="preload-image displayed-image" alt="thumbnail" />';
                                } else {
                                    echo display_post_image (
                                        $post->ID,
                                        $have_image_url=$thumbnail_image_url,
                                        $link=false,
                                        $type="portfolio-small",
                                        $post->post_title,
                                        $class="preload-image displayed-image"
                                    );
                                }
                                ?>
                                <span class="ajax-image-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>         
                                </a>
                        </li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif;?>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php
                require ( MTHEME_INCLUDES . 'clients.php' );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

`

Comment: What is the value of $categories after the get_categories call??

Comment: tip: if you mention a specific line number, MARK WHICH LINE IT IS in the code. especially when it's line 62 of Gazillions, and buried somewhere in the middle. put in a few comments, SOMETHING to show where 62 is.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the function `get_categories` is not returning any valid array in the following line.

```
$categories=  get_categories('child_of='.$portfolio_cat_ID.'&orderby=slug&taxonomy=types&title_li=');
```

Hence, `foreach` can not iterate on `$categories`